# How does Storm handle with Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, clojure, garbage-collection, real-time, apache-storm

**How does Storm handle with Garbage Collection?** And what is the reason of its fast performance. Is it because Disruptor-Pattern or there is another thing I am missing.

Comment: This question is too broad, IMHO. One comment about GC: There is nothing special about it in Storm.

Comment: Fast performance by what metric? And faster in comparison to what? You should ask a more detailed question.

Comment: As @MatthiasJ.Sax has said,storm is just like any other jvm application.

Answer (score 1):

One executor is a JVM thread.

To gain visibility over Garbage Colection you need to configure **worker.childopts** property in the storm.yaml.

```
worker.childopts: "-XX:+PrintCGTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc: /opt/storm/logs/worker%ID%-jvm-gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=1M
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime"
```

And now you are ready to inspect the Garbage Colector output

Comment: thank you answer, and I just wanted to know the role of LMAX Disruptor as it is used in inter-thread communication in Storm and that all memory for the ring-buffer is pre-allocated on start up, and how this pre-allocation affects GC

Comment: LMAX Distruptor is a inter threading messaging library. It's used for the queues which handle the message transfer between executors. Each of this queues has 2 roles, outgoing disruptor tuples for executers emiting tuples to the queue, and incoming disruptor queue for the executers reading from the queue.

Comment: Hi, I added this to my Yaml, along with code to set the String in my Topologies' configuration `conf.put(Config.WORKER_CHILDOPTS, config.getWorkerChildopts());` But I can't find the GC logs. I changed the -loggc argument to the same directory where I see the worker/supervisor/etc... logs, but no GC logs. Any suggestions?